# How to get the global search center url

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I wanted to get the global search center url which is set in the Search Service Application.Is there any direct api access to get the search center url ?

-Sharath

Comment: What version of SharePoint? And what type of code are you looking for? C#? Javascript? COM, SOM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming 2013 and Powershell:

```
$ssa = Get-SPEnterpriseSearchServiceApplication
$ssa.SearchCenterUrl
```

Comment: Thanks, yes it for 2013 version. I was looking for c# version.On digging further looks  I was looking how SharePoint does it internally and looks like they are building and caching it (Found in Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchCommon --> BuildSearchCenterUrl)

Comment: Yes I should guess on something like that, since on Site Collection level you can use a token to point at the SearchCenterUrl

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, yes it for 2013 version. I was looking for c# version.On digging further looks  I was looking how SharePoint does it internally and looks like they are building and caching it (Found in Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.SearchCommon --> BuildSearchCenterUrl). So used the similar thing

```
SPServiceContext svcContext = SPServiceContext.Current;
if (svcContext != null)
{
    SearchServiceApplicationProxy proxy =     svcContext.GetDefaultProxy(typeof(SearchServiceApplicationProxy)) as     SearchServiceApplicationProxy;
    searchCenterUrl = proxy.GetSearchServiceApplicationInfo().SearchCenterUrl;
}
```